# MongoError: no primary server available

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules, mongodb-atlas

I'm runnning a simple restful api with express and mongodb in node.js and I'm getting this error:

```
{ MongoError: no primary server available
at ReplSetState.pickServer (/Users/Computer/Desktop/Username/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/replset_state.js:780:12)
at Timeout._selectServer [as _onTimeout] (/Users/Computer/Desktop/Username/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/replset.js:1147:43)
at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) name: 'MongoError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

[This has already been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706942/mongoerror-no-primary-node-is-available), but the responses were not helpful to me

Comment: Have you added your IP to whitelist in Mongo?

Comment: i am getting the same error. are you on an M0?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, because i forget to whitelist my IP, on mongoDB.Try to do it