# Updating reactivemongo due to PrimaryUnavailableException

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

While updating reactivemongo from `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.5-play26"` to `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.20.13-play26"` I am getting error (ref screenshot). I did a clean compile (sbt clean compile)

[image]

I dont know what this error mean. Here are the details of my project:

- scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
- addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.3")

P.S: My reason of updating the reactivemongo version is I am getting lot of PrimaryUnavailableException and one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706942/mongoerror-no-primary-node-is-available) is to update reactivemongo version. Furthermore, I check my reactivemongo(`"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.5-play26"`) debug logs for the cause and found lot of error(ref below img) before the PrimaryUnavailableException

[image]

I ask you to please guide me on:

1. how to fix errors in 1st image.
2. If possible is updating reactivemongo the only solution to fix PrimaryUnavailableException.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used reactivemongo, but seems your problem comes from [Play Iteratees moved to separate project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration26#Play-Iteratees-moved-to-separate-project).

> Play Iteratees has been moved to a separate library hosted at https://github.com/playframework/play-iteratees. Since Play Iteratees has no dependencies on the rest of Play, the main change is that the you’ll have to specify the library manually:
>
> ```scala
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.6.1"
> ```

I think adding that dependency should fix the compilation error

---

Things that you should have in mind:

- [scala 2.11](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) is not maintained anymore. Latest release was on November 9, 2017
- [play 2.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.9.x/General#End-of-life-(EOL)-Dates) is not maintained anymore. All versions prior to Play 2.8 have reached their end of life and will no longer receive updates.
- [play-iteratees](https://github.com/playframework/play-iteratees) is not maintained anymore. Latest release was on December 20, 2016